Intel Xeon Processor (Skylake, IBRS, no TSX) AVX2 support?
I tried this command to find the model of my intel processor
$ lscpu | grep "Model name"
Model name:            Intel Xeon Processor (Skylake, IBRS, no TSX)

But this seems like a very vague output, and not a specific processor. I couldn't find this listed in https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html#@PanelLabel595
Does anyone know which specific model this is and if it supports AVX2?

Hey Jinkins, unfortunately this seems like a technical support request rather than a hardware recommendation request. In any case, I believe all Skylake processors support AVX2, so you should be fine on that front. That said: interesting issue. Can you tell us what machine it's installed in and what clockspeed it's running at? Might be able to pinpoint it based on that, assuming it's not a dev sample.
